# FBX/GLTF model loading in three,js

Tags: three.js

Can't load any kind of model like (gltf,fbx) also use the https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models doc but can't load the model, but geometry are loaded with out any problem

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8 />
  </head>
  <body>
   
     <script src="three.js"></script>
    <script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
    
    <script src="js/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/FBXLoader.js"></script>
   
    <script>
      let scene, camera, renderer;
      function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,1,5000);
        hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight (0x404040,100);
        scene.add(hlight);

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

  loader.load( 'SimpleSkinning.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

   scene.add( gltf.scene );

  }, undefined, function ( error ) {

   console.error( error );

  } );
      }
      function animate() {
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
      init();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably can't see your model because your camera is configured incorrectly. Right now, it is centered at the origin and thus might be "inside" of your model. Besides, you pass an intensity value of `100` to `AmbientLight` which is way too much. I suggest you remove the parameter for now and just define the light's color. Another tip: You can always use viewers like https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ to ensure if your glTF models are properly loaded. If you see a correct result, there must be something wrong in your app code.